# how to combine the data in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with datasets having records in csv file as:

```
 C_id  C_Name        S_Name                Phone
    97  [Bedsheet]     Shree Collection     77422222
    97  [Bedsheet]    Shree Collection      77422222
    105 [Jeans]       Shree Collection      77422222
    61  [Kurti]       F Fashion             9040645
    95  [Lehenga]     Shree Collection      77422222
    61  [Kurti]        F Fashion        9040645
    73  [Cotton Kurti] F Fashion        9040645
    117 [Earring]              Banti        90406459
```

I want to show the data the data as like :

```
C_id       C_Name                    S_Name              Phone
97,105,95   Bedsheet,Jeans,Lehenga   Shree Collection    77422222
61,73       Kurti,Cotton Kurti       F Fashion           9040645
117          Earring                 Banti               90406459
```

How can this be achieved

Comment: Please show what you've tried. And I assume, you are talking about Pandas DataFrames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `agg` and a couple of `str.join` functions. The parts where you need particular care:

- For `C_id`, since `str.join` requires stringsyou need to convert from`int` to `str`.
- For `C_Name`, you have a series of lists. `itertools.chain` is an efficient way to flatten these lists into a non-nested iterable.

Here's a working example:

```
from itertools import chain

agg_funcs = {'C_id': lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)),
             'C_Name': lambda x: ','.join(chain.from_iterable(x))}

res = df.groupby(['S_Name', 'Phone']).agg(agg_funcs).reset_index()

print(res)

             S_Name     Phone          C_id                           C_Name
0             Banti  90406459           117                          Earring
1         F Fashion   9040645      61,61,73         Kurti,Kurti,Cotton Kurti
2  Shree Collection  77422222  97,97,105,95  Bedsheet,Bedsheet,Jeans,Lehenga
```